# Error: Cannot find module './gitignore'

Tags: angular, git, gitignore, angular6

I have created a angular 6 project. When I run ng build or ng serve I get this error :

```
Cannot find module './gitignore'
Error: Cannot find module './gitignore'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:536:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:466:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\Centralogic\my-project\node_modules\globby\index.js:6:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
```

I have tried deleting and adding it from another project. 
Also tried clearing cache and running npm install.

What have I missed?

Comment: why don't you just create your own `.gitignore` file? Ideally if you have used `angular-cli` to build your project, it would have created one.

Comment: It did and I accidentally seemed to delete it while deleting some files. The gitignore file exists in the project. The issue is, of it saying- module not found.

Comment: are you using any version control system like git ?

Comment: This seems to be no "Angular" problem. It´s not speaking about ngModules, but about Modules. So it´s a problem with a typescript import. Therefore it is very likely, that somewhere you have an "import 'gitignore" in one of your TS files

Comment: @samartajShaikh Yes I am.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly somewhere in code you importing .gitignore file. Please, try to search your project files for that.

Comment: I have checked but am unable to find any reference to this file, in the entire project.

Comment: This is not an answer, please provide a valid answer. with an explanation.

Comment: Note that the error is about `./gitignore`, not `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command, it will update your angular/cli version but find the missing dependency and re-add it.

```
ng update @angular/cli
```